# how can i access to file system and sector of HD by C#.net?

Tags: c#

how can i read sector of HD and access to file syetem and block or cluster of a file,list of bad blocks(FAT) or cluster file(NTFS)?
or access list of  free blocks(FAT) or cluster bitmap(NTFS)?

Comment: You would need to find the Win32 API's to do so (look into the device driver toolkit), and call the functions from your C# via eg. p/invoke.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing this in C#. If there is a Win32 API for this then you can use pInvoke to get access to this API from within your C# app.

Typically, C# is not a good candidate for this sort of thing.